# how to round a float number in MIPS?

Tags: floating-point, mips, rounding

Let's say I have a float number 15.752893 ... in $f0 register.

How can I round that to nearest integer which is 16?

Comment: Look up `round.w.fmt` and `cvt.w.fmt` in the MIPS instruction set reference. Note that if you choose to use `cvt` you'll have to set up the rounding mode in the `FCSR` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below function,

```
round.w.s $f0, $f0
mfc1 $a0, $f0            # moving the integer into $a0
li $v0, 1                # load code to print integer
syscall
```